# Explaining high tech gadgets in an ancient world?

Tags: technology, medieval, ancient-history

In a medieval world, the protagonist has a suit of armor that draws off of his body heat to produce a weak electromagnetic shield that repels against attacks from metal weapons. I don't feel comfortable hand-waving this to such an extreme.

I need at least a plausible explanation as to how he obtained such a ridiculously advanced piece of technology (probably tech of about 200 years in the future) came to be possesed by a person in the times of catapults and swords.

---

***Some possible explanations that allow for such technology:***

1. Time travel- I don't really want to use this one, but I will resort to it as a last effort.
2. An advanced civilization fallen to ruin by some apocalypse, think *Thundarr the barbarian*.

*Are there any more explanations that would be more fitting for the situation?*

Comment: Scientifically, the device isn't plausible. I asked [this question](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10910/6986) about a similar device a while ago. So you're already hand-waving the major part.

Comment: Yep. I know the device isn't plausible, that's why I don't want to handwave the obtaining of a device as well.

Comment: Alternatively, that heat or EM can just simply re-enforce the material making it harder, or more difficult to break, when worn.

Comment: Why not magic? Obvious link to Clarke's third law. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An advanced civilization, lost in the ancient past (even from the point of view of your unrelated medieval civilization) which has left devices in what amounts to an archeological dig.

Alternatively, the device could be left overs from a failed alien landing or colony.

Comment: I've decided to use the failed alien landing. Sounds silly but I like it!